# Получение ID строки из БД

Tags: android, sql

Есть отдельный клас для работы с БД - DB.java, в котором написано как добавлять запись, и в лог выводит `id` строки, но как мне получить этот `rowID` в `Activity`. Нужно это для того чтобы передать `_id` в новый `Activity`

DB.java:

```
public void UsersaddRec(String name, String userp2, String userp3, String userp4, String user1notif, String user2notif, String user3notif, String user4notif) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
    cv.put(COLUMN_USERP2, userp2);
    cv.put(COLUMN_USERP3, userp3);
    cv.put(COLUMN_USERP4, userp4);
    cv.put(COLUMN_USER1NOTIF, user1notif);
    cv.put(COLUMN_USER2NOTIF, user2notif);
    cv.put(COLUMN_USER3NOTIF, user3notif);
    cv.put(COLUMN_USER4NOTIF, user4notif);
    //mDB.insert(DB_TABLE_USER, null, cv);
    // вставляем запись и получаем ее ID
    long rowID = mDB.insert(DB_TABLE_USER, null, cv);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row inserted, ID = " + rowID);
}
```

Запись в `Activity` добавляется так:

```
 alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            db.UsersaddRec(input.getText().toString(), "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
                            db.SystemaddRec(input.getText().toString(), "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
                            db.InpOutAddRec(input.getText().toString(), "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
                            db.OtherTextaddRec(input.getText().toString(), "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
                            Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(device_manage_lw.this, device_manage.class);
                            myIntent1.putExtra("name", input.getText().toString());

                            startActivity(myIntent1);
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В классе `DB.java` измените функцию добавления вот так:

```
public long UsersaddRec(String name, String userp2, String userp3, String userp4, String user1notif, String user2notif, String user3notif, String user4notif) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
    cv.put(COLUMN_USERP2, userp2);
    cv.put(COLUMN_USERP3, userp3);
    cv.put(COLUMN_USERP4, userp4);
    cv.put(COLUMN_USER1NOTIF, user1notif);
    cv.put(COLUMN_USER2NOTIF, user2notif);
    cv.put(COLUMN_USER3NOTIF, user3notif);
    cv.put(COLUMN_USER4NOTIF, user4notif);
    //mDB.insert(DB_TABLE_USER, null, cv);
    // вставляем запись и получаем ее ID
    long rowID = mDB.insert(DB_TABLE_USER, null, cv);
    return rowID;
}
```

Соответственно, вызываете функцию вот так:

```
long rowID = db.UsersaddRec(input.getText().toString(), "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
```